# Como converter múltiplas folhas .XLSL para .CSV de um livro e exportar individualmente para o ambiente de trabalho?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Pretendo guardar no ambiente de trabalho as múltiplas folhas pelo próprio nome. E que sejam convertidas de .xlsx para .csv (separado por virgula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO:

```
Sub guardar()
Dim folha As Worksheet

For Each folha In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
folha.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\CSV\" & folha.Name & ".csv", xlCSV

Next
End Sub
```